# Conceptual Ice Water Equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

We observe that when we apply pressure on on Ice Water equilibrium system then more of ice melts..
Ice(more Volume) + Heat ----><----- Water (Less volume)
If we increase pressure then volume decreases and Le chatilier's principle says that inorder to minimise the effect It will move in such a direction which is favourable in minimising...
Now,By increasing pressure if volume decreases then the reaction has a tendency to go in such a direction in which volume will increase that is it should form ice because that has more volume than water **So why is it not converting into ice or water forming reaction slowing down instead water is now formed more rapidly ?** **

Comment: Clean up the question.  In the same sentence volume both increases and decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood le chatlier principal.
By saying that" its effect to reduce", it meant causal effect is to be reduce. So, here he meant on increasing pressure since volume decrease , here he meant to move from more volume towards that direction which has less volume, where increased pressure has less effect.

He hasn't decreased volume , decrease in volume is result. He increased pressure, so, he wants to decrease pressure. when he apply pressure on ice it is converted into water and pressure is decreased. It is like an inflated ballon. If balloon has air filled due to more air, baloon apply more force on air. Where as if we have something like nail in it, negligible pressure is applied on it.

Comment: Do u mean whatever effect is done that is nullified

Comment: Now if he has decreased volume wouldn't he increase it ??

Comment: No, whatever the cause is , this cause is nullified.

Comment: Sorry I am student.Someone else may give?

Comment: well if you still want it is 9215203069